# coord_sf forces ggplot grid lines?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf, tigris

I'm using `ggplot2` and the `sf` and `tigris` packages to draw some maps (with `geom_sf()`). I was finding that I couldn't turn off grid lines, despite calling `theme(panel.grid = element_blank())` and it seems like it's due to using `coord_sf`.

Here's a non-map example, that's a simpler way to reproduce my issue

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10),
                  y=rnorm(10))

# grid lines, as expected
ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

```
# no grid lines, as expected
ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_light() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

```
# why does this have grid lines?
ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_sf() +
  theme_light() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

I'd like to use `coord_sf` but also turn off gridlines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As markus linked, https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2071, this is a bug, adding **datum=NA** to coord_sf() fixes:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  coord_sf(datum=NA) +
  theme_light() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```